# How can I stop an NSMutableArray in my AppDelegate from being deallocated?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my AppDelegate I have declared an NSMutableArray as a property:

```
@property NSMutableArray  *delegateValuableItems;
```

and allocated it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.delegateValuableItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
```

I have several view controllers in my app, but only one accesses this property:

```
[appDelegate.delegateValuableItems addObject:@"a"];
```

having previously defined the AppDelegate as a property in the view controller:

```
@property AppDelegate       *appDelegate;
```

and referenced it in viewDidLoad:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

My problem is that if the app is left alone for a few minutes the NSMutableArray is deallocated.

At least I think it is.

Everything works if I run through the app and enter all the details straight away, but if I leave it running for a few minutes `[appDelegate.delegateValuableItems addObject:@"a"];` doesn't add the object to the array.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Probably that's because iOS sleeps your app after 10 minutes it has been in background. Are you sending your app to background? And make sure your property is declared as strong: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray delegateValuableItems`

Comment: Does the app crash when you try adding it?

Comment: Properties became strong by default in XCode 4.3. If you are using an earlier version you need to write:
@property (strong) NSMutableArray  *delegateValuableItems;

Comment: This happens before iOS sleeps, I'm not sending the app to the background and the app does not crash, but I will try defining `(nonatomic, strong)`. thx

Comment: ok, I'll just try nonatomic then thx :)

Comment: nonatomic didnt work :(

Comment: How are you checking that object isn't added to delegateValuableItems ?

Comment: I'm logging the array to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access `delegateValuableItems` only from one class, this property should be only in that class. However, if you want to access it from the whole application, but being sure that it´s always the same instance (because if you declared it in the app delegate, probably that´s because you want only one instance for the whole app), then you should use a Singleton.

You should have a model object that holds the NSMutableArray, and that model should be a Singleton, to make sure you're always accessing to the same instance of the NSMutableArray.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're right about why I declared it in the AppDelegate. I'll try a singleton. thx

Comment: Well, after trying a whole bunch of things that didn't work and reverting the code manually I couldn't reproduce the problem, but I've implemented the singleton anyway to protect against recurrence, so thanks :)